# Including JS and CSS in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, go

I'm running an http server instance with Go and I would like to return the HTML doc to a client, but the JS and the CSS files are not working. How do I make the JS and CSS get sent along with the HTML if they are in different files?

Go Code

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("webpage.html")
    s := string(file)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, s)
}
```

webpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>html file</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Click to change color</h1>
        <script src="changeColor.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And changeColor.js

```
function init(){
var h1tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
h1tags[0].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(){
    this.style.color = '#000000';
}
onload = init;
```

CSS is in a file called styles.css in the same directory as the HTML doc.

Comment: You'll need to serve the js and css file as well. A common practise is to put them in a static directory and serve the static directory all together.

Comment: See [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer). If renaming the HTML file to index.html is an option, you can get away with a single handler, otherwise you need some special code for the root path.

Comment: Do you know how HTTP and HTML works? First the web browser asks the web server for the HTML. Then the browser parses the HTML and finds that it should also get some other files like CSS, JS, and images. Thus, those files are not sent along with the HTML but in separate requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your Go code, you need to do it like this :

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

http.HandleFunc("/changeColor.js", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "changeColor.js")
})

http.HandleFunc("/styles.css", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "styles.css")
})

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Because go server for this line

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="styles.css"/>
```

looks this pattern "/styles.css" and your server does not handle this request.

And you can replace this code

```
http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
```

whit this

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "webpage.html")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a file server for handling static content(e.g. css,js,img).
For example, you have a directory structure as below.

```
   static     
      css
        styles.css
      js
        changeColor.js
```

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
   // other handlers
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And you can access CSS and js in your HTML file as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "log"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Got request:", r.URL.Path)

    var contentType string
    var fileName string

    switch r.URL.Path {
    case "/":
        contentType = "text/html"
        fileName = "webpage.html"

    case "/changeColor.js":
        contentType = "text/javascript"
        fileName = "changeColor.js"

    case "/styles.css":
        contentType = "text/css"
        fileName = "styles.css"

    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Println("Bad request (unknown file)")
        return
    }

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        log.Println("File not found")
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    s := string(file)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, s)
}
```